# Using MultiFieldPanel inside a StructBlock

Tags: django, wagtail

If you have a StructBlock class (used inside a StreamField)... Can you still use the Wagtail panels to group some fields (eg MultiFieldPanel) and (ideally!) use the collapsible class on the panel to hide them in some kind of "Advanced" panel?

I have tried adding the `block.TextBlock` definitions into the array for a panel the, however neither the Panel nor the Fields appeared in the form.

I cant see anything in the docs about using Panels in StructBlocks:

- https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.8.1/reference/pages/panels.html
- https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.8.1/topics/streamfield.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use panels inside StreamField blocks. However, by overriding `form_template` on your StructBlock class you can set up whatever HTML structure you like:

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/streamfield_blocks.html#custom-editing-interfaces-for-structblock